# Python: Extract hashtags out of a text file

Tags: python, hashtag

So, I've written the code below to extract hashtags and also tags with '@', and then append them to a list and sort them in descending order. The thing is that the text might not be perfectly formatted and not have spaces between each individual hashtag and the following problem may occur - as it may be checked with the #print statement inside the for loop :
*#socality#thisismycommunity#themoderndayexplorer#modernoutdoors#mountaincultureelevated*

So, the .split() method doesn't deal with those. What would be the best practice to this issue?

[Here is the .txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/odjsusyhtyipz83/tags.txt?dl=0)

Grateful for your time.

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "tags.txt"
handle = open(name)
tags = dict()
lst = list()

for line in handle :
    hline = line.split()
    for word in hline:
        if word.startswith('@') : tags[word] = tags.get(word,0) + 1
        else :
            tags[word] = tags.get(word,0) + 1
        #print(word)

for k,v in tags.items() :
    tags_order = (v,k)
    lst.append(tags_order)

lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)[:34]
print('Final Dictionary: ' , '\n')
for v,k in lst :
    print(k , v, '')
```

Comment: If text contains only tags and profiles but not well-formatted, you can use regular expressions. They fits such tasks very well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regular expression. There are only a few limits; a tag must start with either `#` or `@`, and it may not contain any spaces or other whitespace characters.

This code

```
import re
tags = []
with open('../Downloads/tags.txt','Ur') as file:
    for line in f.readline():
        tags += re.findall(r'[#@][^\s#@]+', line)
```

creates a list of all tags in the file. You can easily adjust it to store the found tags in your dictionary; instead of storing the result straight away in `tags`, loop over it and do with each item as you please.

The regex is built up from these two custom character classes:

- `[#@]` - either the single character `#` or `@` at the start
- `[^\s#@]+` - a sequence of *not* any single whitespace character (`\s` matches all whitespace such as space, tab, and returns), `#`, or `@`; at least one, and as many as possible.

So `findall` starts matching at the start of any tag and then grabs as much as it can, stopping only when encountering any of the "not" characters.

`findall` returns a list of matching items, which you can immediately add to an existing list, or loop over the found items in turn:

```
for tag in re.findall(r'[#@][^\s#@]+', line):
    # process "tag" any way you want here
```

The source text file contains Windows-style `\r\n` line endings, and so I initially got a lot of empty "lines" on my Mac. Opening the text file in [Universal newline mode](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/node7.html) makes sure that is handled transparently by the line reading part of Python.

Comment: this takes care of the simple cases but what about corner cases like word boundaries: `hello#tag` and trailing special characters like `#tag...`.